# About high dimensional integrals

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization, series-expansion

I want to be able to do high dimensional integrals like,

(..naively I wrote it as this..)

```
Nc = 12; Nn = 12; 
f [x_] := (Sin[x])^2;
g[n_, x_] := Cos[n*(x)];
Integrate[ (Times @@ 
    Flatten@Table[
      f[(a[i] - a[j])/2], {i, 1, Nc - 1}, {j, i + 1, Nc}])*
  SeriesCoefficient [ 
   Series [ 
    Exp[ Plus @@ 
      Flatten@Table [   ((4)/(n (x^(-n/2) + x^(n/2))))*(Plus @@ 
           Flatten@
            Table[g[n, a[i] - a[j]], {i, 1, Nc}, {j, 1, Nc}]), {n, 1, 
         Nn}] ], {x, 0, 1}], 1/2], {a[1], -\[Pi], \[Pi]} , {a[
   2], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}  , {a[3], -\[Pi], \[Pi]} , {a[
   4], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {a[5], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {a[
   6], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {a[7], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {a[
   8], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {a[9], -\[Pi], \[Pi]} , {a[
   10], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {a[11], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {a[12], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]
```

But the above has been like running for ages without an output.

I would like to know how I can optimize this work so that I can push this to higher levels. For instance I would like to extract higher powers of $x$ rather than $1/2$ as in the above example and also to more variables than $12$ as above.

Comment: ...I don't think it's reasonable to expect a 12-fold integral with some amount of complexity to execute quickly. You may want to figure out if you can simplify the beastie further (e.g. integrating "easy parts") before proceeding further.

Comment: I think there was a bug that required becalming. Is 0 the expected result?

Comment: The results for Nc from 1 to 6 seem to be {8*Pi, 8*Pi^2, 3*Pi^3, (3*Pi^4)/8, (15*Pi^5)/1024, (45*Pi^6)/262144} so I do not think it will be 0 for 12

Comment: @RolfMertig I also get ` (15*Pi^5)/1024` using the method described below for n=5.

Comment: @RolfMertig and (45Pi^6)/262144 for n=6 ;-)

Comment: @chris can you get n=7? How long does it take to get to n=6?

Comment: @chris: for n=7 my code needs 35 minutes and I get (315 Pi^7)/536870912

Comment: And for n=8 I get Out of Memory ... I doubt that this is solvable in Mathematica alone for Nc=12.

Comment: @user6818 Where did this type of integral show up? How important is it to find a solution? Did you try to solve it numerically?

Comment: @chris (..and Rolf Mertig..) thanks for all the efforts. But something seems to be going wrong here - I am expecting the value of the integral to asymptote for higher and higher values of $Nc$ - and the asymptotic value is to be some small rational number -

Comment: @RolfMertig (and chris) May be you can look into this other question of mine (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13721/about-finding-residues-of-multi-dimensional-complex-functions)where I have asked about a possible reformulation of the integration that I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This integral is doable using the following method:

1) `Expand` the integrant

2) `TrigExpand` the result

3) apply the following rule (to collect for `a[1]`)

```
 Exp[x_] :> Exp[Collect[x, a[1]]]
```

4) apply (possibly in //) this rule to the terms which do not involve `a[1]`

```
 Exp[Complex[0, c_] a[1] +  b_.] -> (2*E^b*Sinh[Pi*(Complex[0, c])])/(Complex[0, c])}
```

(which corresponds to integrating over a[1]) and multiply terms which do not involve `a[1]` by `2Pi`

5) iterate step 3 and 4) but for `a[2]... a[12]`

In short, we just tell give mathematica a rule for each brick element integration.
I tried it for 1/63th of the terms involved in step 1 and it works.
Interestingly this part of the integration did give me a zero contribution for 
terms depending on `a[1]`.

I can't give you the full answer because my laptops gets too hot ;-)
I ll run it on a workstation and let you know.

Comment: Sure, I did something similar, but I cannot get the answer for 12 this way. For 6 I need 45 seconds.