# Symbolic integration in the complex plane

Tags: numerics, symbolic, complex, calculus-and-analysis

**Context**

While answering this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13728/1089), I defined (symbolic and numerical) path integrations as follows

```
 ContourIntegrate[f_, par : (z_ -> g_), {t_, a_, b_}] := 
       Integrate[Evaluate[(f /. par) D[g, t]], {t, a, b}]

 NContourIntegrate[f_, par : (z_ -> g_), {t_, a_, b_}] := 
       NIntegrate[Evaluate[D[g, t] (f /. par) /. t -> t1], {t1, a, b}]
```

I also defined a piecewise contour

```
Clear[pw]; 
pw[t_, a_: 1] = Piecewise[{{a Exp[I t], t < Pi}, {-a + 2 a (t - Pi)/Pi, t >= Pi}}]
ParametricPlot[pw[t] // {Re[#], Im[#]} &, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

While checking these routines on wikipedia [examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration),
I tried numerically

```
 Table[NContourIntegrate[Exp[I i x]/(x^2 + 1), x -> pw[t, 2], {t, 0, 2 Pi}], {i, 2, 5}] // Chop

(* {0.425168,0.156411,0.0575403,0.0211679} *)
```

which corresponds accurately to (see [example II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration) for Cauchy distributions)

```
Table[Exp[-i] Pi, {i, 2, 5}] // N
```

On the other hand, the symbolic integration

```
ContourIntegrate[Exp[I x]/(x^2 + 1), x -> pw[t, 2], {t, 0, 2 Pi}] // FullSimplify
```

returns 0.

**Question**

What am I doing wrong?

**Attempts**

[Example I and III](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration)  work ;-)

```
ContourIntegrate[1/(x^2 + 1)^2, x -> pw[ t, 2], {t, 0, 2 Pi}] // FullSimplify
NContourIntegrate[1/(x^2 + 1)^2, x -> pw[ t, 2], {t, 0, 2 Pi}] // Chop

(* Pi/2  1.5708 *)
```

and

```
NContourIntegrate[1/I/x/(1 + 3 ((x + 1/x)/2)^2), x -> Exp[I t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]//Chop
ContourIntegrate[1/I/x/(1 + 3 ((x + 1/x)/2)^2), x -> Exp[I t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]

(* 3.14159  Pi *)
```

Comment: For Example II, with exactly the same code as you have (except that I changed your `x` more suggestively to `z`), Mathematica 8.0.4 is giving me result Pi/E. This agrees with the answer provided by the Residue Theorem.

Comment: @murray uhm... it seems you are right..

Comment: The answer you got from `ContourIntegrate` in Example IIIa is correct -- and is the same, except for form, as the answer $\pi \sqrt{2}/4$ obtained from substitution and the Residue Theorem as in the wikipedia page you cite.

Comment: @murray right again... ghosh I guess I am out of my mind..

Comment: @murray it seems I must have a name conflict with my init file...

Comment: @murray thanks for your time. i ll erase my question

Comment: But you have a nicely defined contour integration routine. Note that it's certainly not necessary to pack parameterization of the entire contour into a single `Piecewise` function; that just forces one do some contortions to get the `t`-value at the end of one piece to match up with the `t`-value at the start of the second piece. It seems it would be simpler to separately parameterize the semicircle and the $x$-axis and evaluate the contour integrals of both; then just add.

Comment: @murray I found my bug. `SetOptions[Integrate, GenerateConditions -> False]; ContourIntegrate[Exp[ I x]/(x^2 + 1), x -> pw[t, 2], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]` yields 0 whereas if `SetOptions[Integrate, GenerateConditions -> True]` it produces the correct answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem lies with the fact that my init.m file has

```
 SetOptions[Integrate, GenerateConditions -> False]
```

If I use

```
 SetOptions[Integrate, GenerateConditions -> True]
```

or define

```
 ContourIntegrate[f_, par : (z_ -> g_), {t_, a_, b_}] := 
   Integrate[Evaluate[(f /. par) D[g, t]], {t, a, b}, GenerateConditions -> True]
```

the discrepency vanishes.

I guess this makes this question too narrow to be of general interest!

In any case, the bring home message is don't do complex integration without paying attention to branch-cuts !

Comment: No, I don't think this is too narrow an issue: the post might help somebody else with a mysterious result!