# FourierSeries for rational function looks wrong

Tags: bugs, fourier-analysis

**Bug introduced in Version 8 or earlier, and persisting through 12.1.**

---

I have the following code:

```
ser[x_] = FourierSeries[(π^2 + a)/(3 x^2 + a), x, 10] // N // Chop
```

It gives me some series, which I then try to plot. And surprisingly, the result isn't even similar to the function I passed to `FourierSeries[]`: for comparison, I've used this code:

```
Plot[{ser[x], 1000 (π^2 + a)/(3 x^2 + a)}, {x, -π, π}]
```

[image: output]

Fourier transform for function given in documentation works correctly, while for this one doesn't. I've tried using directly the formula given in documentation as default formula (used `NIntegrate[]`), and that gives me expected results.
What have I done wrong? Is this a bug?

*Addition to answer comments:*
[image: some more code]

As one can see, the Fourier coefficients computed via `NIntegrate[]` are *quite* different from ones generated by `FourierCoefficient[]`.

*Update:*
As pointed in comments, setting `GenerateConditions->True` appears to yield correct result, not generating any conditions though. Why should this be needed?

Comment: The order is too small for this function then.

Comment: No it's not. I've tried using normal NIntegrate[] to the same order, it gives correct shape.

Comment: Actually `FourierCosSeries` works fine. Are you sure it can't be the feature of the Laplace distribution for its series to behave like this?

Comment: @swish yes, see update. It's Fourier coefficients which look wrong, not the function behavior.

Comment: What value do you use for `a`?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries $a=1$

Comment: Yeah, I figured that. `Integrate` does also yield a different coefficient, both in v8 and v9.

Comment: Try `GenerateConditions -> True`, then it will yield the correct result somehow, without any actual conditions generated. And maybe edit you question asking why `FourierCoefficient` does this.

Comment: Hmm, funny. What's your default setting for `FourierParameters`?

Comment: @J.M. Defaults are, as said in documentation, {1,1}. Setting them explicitly doesn't change results. Neither does {1,-2Pi} change behavior.

Comment: The problem could be boiled down to this function `1/(x^2 + 1)` - no need to put `a` and Pi there - just confuses things. It's a bell function. To realize the problem one should compare to another bell, like `Sech[x]`. 5 terms or even 3 will be enough. No need to go numeric either.

Comment: Re update, see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46492

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something strange is going on here. Here is a computation which illustrates the issue without some of the extraneous aspects.

> wrong = FourierCoefficient[1/(x^2 + 1), x, 1]

The variable `wrong` now contains what `FourierCoefficient` thinks is the coefficient of $e^{i x}$ in the fourier series of $1/(x^2+1)$. According to the documentation for `FourierCoefficient` (v. 8) "The $n^{th}$ coefficient in the Fourier series of $f(t)$ is by default given by $\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} f(t) e^{-int} dt$." In other words, `wrong` should be equal to $\frac{1}{2 \pi} 
\int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \frac{e^{-it}}{1+t^2} dt$. Let's put that integral directly into Mathematica:

> right = Integrate[E^(-I x)/(x^2 + 1), {x, -Pi, Pi}] / (2 Pi)

So we should have `wrong == right`. In fact:

> Simplify[wrong - right]
>
> (* Output -E/2 *)

---

It looks like `FourierCoefficient[]` is computing $\int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \frac{e^{-i t}}{t^2+1} dt$ along the wrong path in the complex plane. If you think of $\frac{e^{-i t}}{t^2+1}$ as a function of a complex variable $t$, it has poles at $\pm i$. The value of the integral will be different depending on whether you take a path that goes over both poles, under both or (the correct choice) along the real axis between the poles. If we go over the pole at $i$ when we should have gone under, we pick up an extra $(2 \pi i) R$ where $R$ is the [residue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_%28complex_analysis%29) at $i$.

> Residue[E^(-I*t)/(t^2 + 1), {t, I}]
>
> (* Output - I*E/2 *)

So $R= -ie/2$, making the integral off by $- (2 \pi i) (i e/2) = \pi e$. Then we have a $\frac{1}{2 \pi}$ in front of the integral, so our final answer is off by $e/2$.

Comment: The error even affects the cognate function `FourierCoefficient[]`. Very suspicious...

Comment: Edited my example to use `FourierCoefficient`, so that I don't have to muck around in the interior of `FourierSeries` output. Thanks!

Comment: `FourierCoefficient[1/(x^2 + 1), x, 1, Assumptions -> -Pi < x < Pi]` gives the correct answer.

Comment: Now that's just weird. Here we thought we don't have to add the assumption that the integration variable is within the integration interval... :D

Comment: Quite an interesting answer, thanks. Also, setting `Assumptions->Element[x, Reals]` appears enough for it to work.