# When to use GenerateConditions -> True

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, options

Many functions, usuallly those involving integration, take a `GenerateConditions` option which often defaults to `False`, or at least it does for `Expectation` and and the Fourier transform related functions.
In what situations should the default be changed? What are the pros and cons?

Comment: Ther is some info in the article here. http://www.sigsam.org/bulletin/articles/175/lichtblau.pdf

Comment: See also http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13458

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `False` setting can be useful when one wants an integral that is classically divergent. Or when one wants a result without provisos. A downside is greater chance of an incorrect result. A `True` setting is thus useful for the opposite, e.g. avoidance of finite results for divergent integrals. It can also be useful for more careful checking in multivariate integration, since the default `Automatic` setting only behaves as `True` for the final integration.

--- edit ---

Many functions, notably transforms such as `FourierTransform`, work with generalized functions. The first approach to them involves table lookup. If that fails, a next attempt might use the classical definition via definite integral. Since many of these do not classically converge, `Integrate` will (by default) be called with `GenerateConditions -> False`.

In a better world, singular integrals with finite interpretations would be handled with an option different from the one that determines whether or not to issue provisos. Maybe some day...

--- end edit ---

Comment: According to the documentation, the default setting is False rather than Automatic for most of the functions I have looked at. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Re `False` default setting, see edit