# Generate conditions seems to not work

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, evaluation, symbolic, conditional

I am trying to compute the following integral

```
Integrate[E^(I*k*Omega*t), {t,0,T}, GenerateConditions->True]
```

for which Mathematica returns

```
((-I)*(-1+E^(I*k*Omega*T)))/(k*Omega)
```

apparently not recognizing that `k` can be 0. Why `GenerateConditions` doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Limit[((-I)*(-1+E^(I*k*Omega*T)))/(k*Omega), k -> 0] gives the right answer:T.

Comment: Assuming[k == 0, Integrate[E^(I*k*Omega*t), {t, 0, T}]] also gives T.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, but here the point is to automatically generate the conditions for which the result changes. The reason is that in the real case I have several `k`-variables, and I expect that there will be lots of conditions.

Comment: (1) Integrate will not catch conditions that are discrete. (2) As was pointed out already in comments, the result is correct anyway; the singularity is removable (e.g. via `Limit`).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because its asker simply does not understand that the result he contests is actually correct.

Comment: I don't think the question should be closed because it points out a limitation of *Mathematica* that others should understand.  I do not that think that the answer is strictly correct because the result cannot be evaluated at `k == 0`.  To be able to get a result in a form that can be evaluated at zero seems a quite reasonable expectation; however, such an expectation is misplaced.  (Comments are limited in length but roughly to me, using `Limit` to get to the correct answer is an afterthought, not a procedure pointed out in the docs.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Daniel Lichtblau's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) comment seems like an answer that is worth putting in an answer:

> (1) `Integrate` will not catch conditions that are discrete. (2) As was pointed out already in comments, the result is correct anyway; the singularity is removable (e.g. via `Limit`).

*Edit:* I might add that `GenerateConditions` might yield a [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) but not a piecewise function, which is what the complete specification of the OP's integral would require.  `ConditionalExpression[expr, condition]` implies that the answer is `Undefined` when the `condition` is not met.

Comment: It seems that @Daniel Lichtblau is right, since I've tried `Integrate[x^n, x, GenerateConditions -> True]`, and the result fails by setting `n` to `-1`. However for this case also the `Limit` is not correct.

Comment: @Jommy `Limit` does not work because the integral is indefinite.  It works on `Integrate[x^n, {x, a, b}, Assumptions -> 0 < a < b]`. I believe `GenerateConditions` defaults to `True` for single integrals.  See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13458 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46492.

Comment: @Jommy  Here's an example where `Limit` fails: `Integrate[Sin[a/x]/x, {x, 0, 1}]`.  The answer (or its limit) does not agree with the actual integral for `a == 0 + t I`, for any real value for `t`.