# How to force correct answers for Integrals of Cos[mx]*Cos[nx]?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

This is a big problem if you do anything with a Fourier Series.  This statement:

```
Assuming[Element[{m, n}, Integers], Integrate[Cos[m*x]*Cos[n*x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]]
```

returns 0.  But the right answer is non-zero whenever $|m|=|n|$.

This other arrangement:

```
Integrate[Cos[m*x]*Cos[n*x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},  Assumptions -> Element[{m, n}, Integers]]
```

gives an answer that goes $0/0$ when $|m|=|n|$.

I know there are generic and non-generic answers, but this is pretty dang simple.  And Fourier series work is pretty common!

What I need is a solution that will work when I didn't know there was a `Cos[n x]` in it:

```
Integrate[Integrate[Cos[m*x]*f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},  Assumptions -> Element[{m}, Integers]]
```

If my `f[x]` happens to have a `Cos[]` in it, Mathematica will give me wrong answers, unless I anticipate the situation and code around it.  How could I do that?

Comment: Mathematica returns [generic results](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GenericAndNonGenericCases.html).  You are trying to get a non-generic result.  You will likely need to change your assumptions to force Mathematica to consider the non-generic case.

Comment: [1](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19833/usage-of-assuming-for-integration) [2](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51967/generate-conditions-seems-to-not-work) [3](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Oct/msg00119.html)

Comment: No, it's not simple. Not at all. I suspect it would require a considerable amount of special case pattern matching to implement any subset of integrals of this type. Seen next comment for why current method cannot do these.

Comment: Currently much assumption handling is accomplished under the hood with `Refine` and `Simplify`. In a case like this, assumptions of integrality will have the predictable result. Here is a smaller variant: `Refine[Sin[m*Pi]/m, Assumptions->Element[m,Integers]]                   

Out[5]= 0`. If this does not return 0, then `Refine` is effectively useless. And if it does, then `Refine` cannot do better than support a generic result, when used in `Integrate`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  Okay, not that I understand why the bug exists, how do I work around it?  How do I make my integrals of products of sums of trigonometric functions not come out wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very helpful discussion in progress about work-arounds HERE:

[How to code around known MMa special-case failures?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67080/)

Comment: In that case, I shall close this one as a duplicate. Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: @Verbeia  Cool. The follow-up question elicited way more helpful responses.

Answer (score 6):

At least with *Mathematica* version 10.0.1, using option `Assumptions` does provide a correct answer:

```
Integrate[Cos[m*x]*Cos[n*x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   Assumptions -> Element[{m, n}, Integers]] 

(* (Sin[2*(m - n)*Pi]/(m - n) + Sin[2*(m + n)*Pi]/(m + n))/2
```

I don't know why this form of the input leads to a different result than the form using `Assuming`.

Comment: that form also goes 0/0 when |m|==|n|.

Comment: Yes, it's an indeterminate form. `Limit` is a good function for handling those.

Comment: Sure it 'goes 0/0', but so what? It is still correct. Sin[x]/x =1 at x=0.

Comment: @murray, this is why Assuming gives something different: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/when-and-why-are-assuming-and-assumptions-not-equivalent