# How can I make Mathematica catch one-off cases where the answer is different?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I wanted to compute
$$\frac{2}{L}\int_0^L\left(1+2\cos\frac{3 \pi x}{L}\right)\cos\frac{n \pi x}{L}\,dx,$$
so my input was

```mathematica
Assuming[Element[n, Integers], Integrate[(2/L)(1 + 2 Cos[3 Pi x/L])Cos[n Pi x/L], {x, 0, L}]].
```

The answer turns out to be 0 for all $n > 0$ EXCEPT $n = 3$, for which it is $2$. However Mathematica just said the answer is $0$, so I had to know to check that case specifically. How can I type these kinds of expressions in the future to catch one-off cases like this? I know Mathematica cannot just check every $n$ and is using symbolic manipulation to simplify the expression, but even when I bound $n$ in a very tight interval like $[2, 4]$ it said 0.

Comment: Maybe there is a specific reason you want to compute the integral directly  but you might be interested in`FourierCosCoefficient`

Comment: @userrandrand I was not familiar, thank you! However, unless I'm using it wrong, now I am not getting anything close to the answer I am looking for. Maybe a subject for another question....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67080/how-to-code-around-known-mma-special-case-failures).

Comment: @EphraimRuttenberg mathematica has lots of issues one can run into. In those cases it is important to carefully check the documentation,  In particular the Details section and possible issues sections are important when confronted with difficulties, The details section explains that by default `FourierCosCoefficient` computes the integral between 0 and Pi . If you want to compute it over a different interval you need to specify it with `FourierParameters`.