# Solution doesn't have Kronecker delta

Tags: fourier-analysis

If I enter the important integral

```
Integrate[(2/Pi)*Cos[l x] Cos[m x], {x, 0, Pi}]
FullSimplify[%, Element[l, Integers] && Element[m, Integers]]
```

I get the responses:
$$\frac{2l\cos m\pi \sin n\pi-2m\cos l\pi \sin m\pi}{(l^2-m^2)\pi}$$
$$0$$

Clearly this doesn't take into consideration that $l$ may equal $m$. How can I enter an integral with similar assumptions and not allow Mathematica to make a similar mistake? For example, I entered

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[(2/Pi) Sin[x]^2*Cos[l x], {x, 0, Pi}]
, Element[l, Integers]]
```

and it gives me the solution $0$, without considering that $l$ may equal $2$, for which this  solution is not valid. I am lucky my professor caught the mistake, but I am looking a method to do it so it gives me the Kronecker delta, if possible. Thanks.

Edit: My example was copied incorrectly; what I am looking for is a ubiquitous method that doesn't rely on me already knowing that there may be a Kronecker delta.

Comment: Not really a duplicate, but it should answer the question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51967/generate-conditions-seems-to-not-work

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

int[l_Integer, m_Integer] = Assuming[{l, m} ∈ Integers,
  Piecewise[{
     {Integrate[(2/Pi)*Cos[l x] Cos[m x] /. l -> m, {x, 0, Pi}], 
      l == m}},
    Integrate[(2/Pi)*Cos[l x] Cos[m x], {x, 0, Pi}]] // Simplify]
```

[image]

Or,

```
Piecewise[Assuming[Element[{l, m}, Integers] && #,
    {Simplify[Integrate[(2/Pi)*Cos[l x] Cos[m x], {x, 0, Pi}]], #}] & /@
  {l == m, True}]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I copied my second example incorrectly. I have edited my question; but I am looking for a way to get the correct answer without specifying that it should look for the case $l=m$ separately (because I don't always know when it might be different).

Comment: A little faster: `Simplify[Piecewise[{{Integrate[(2/Pi)*Cos[l x] Cos[m x] /. l -> m, {x, 0, Pi}], l == m}, {Integrate[(2/Pi)*Cos[l x] Cos[m x], {x, 0, Pi}],l != m}}], {l, m} \[Element] Integers]`