# Why does Mathematica say $\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1.0}{xyz}\,dz\,dy\,dx=0$?

Tags: numerical-integration, calculus-and-analysis

Mathematica 9 says that $\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1.0}{xyz}\,dz\,dy\,dx=0$ and $\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1}{xyz}\,dz\,dy\,dx=0$.

```
Integrate[1.0/(x y z), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

I must be missing something obvious. What?

[image]

For what it’s worth, [Wolfram Alpha gives the same incorrect answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B1.0%2F%28x%20y%20z%29%2C%20%7Bx%2C%200%2C%201%7D%2C%20%7By%2C%200%2C%201%7D%2C%20%7Bz%2C%200%2C%201%7D%5D) if the numerator is $1.0$, but it correctly says the integral diverges when the numerator is $1$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Please include in your question the actual Mathematic code you used to obtain this unexpected result.  Also, please be aware that this site does not address Alpha questions except those involved in calling Alpha from Mathematica.

Comment: If you do: `Integrate[1/(x y z), {x, a, 1}, {y, a, 1}, {z, a, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> a \[Element] Reals]`  you get the following: `ConditionalExpression[-Log[a]^3, 0 <= a < 1]`
Then take the limit as a->0 by doing: `Limit[ConditionalExpression[-Log[a]^3, 0 <= a < 1], a -> 0]` which gives infinity. Interesting that it gives zero, (Mathematica 10.1 does too)

Comment: Thanks. I’m made it clearer the question is about Mathematica, not Wolfram Alpha. I thought it was worth noting the wrong Wolfram Alpha answer, too, since it suggests the problem is not that I’m running Mathematica 9.

Comment: Mathematica is supposed to be able to handle improper integrals on its own, though. The documentation says “Integrate gives exact answers to many improper integrals,” though I guess that could leave open the possibility that it gives wrong answers to many improper integrals as well.

Comment: It has to do with the default behavior of `GenerateConditions` in multivariate integrals. Setting it explicitly to `True` will help in this case. Some explanation may be found [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13275/what-exactly-does-generateconditions-do) or [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46453/when-to-use-generateconditions-true).

Comment: By the way, comments will go automatically only to original posters and whoever gave the particular response under which the comment appears.  I only saw the answer request by accident. To reach anyone else e.g. another commenter, be sure to use the "at" sign to get their attention (it's kind of like raising from the spirit world, I think).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It has to do with the default behavior of `GenerateConditions` in multivariate integrals. Setting it explicitly to `True` will help in this case. Some explanation may be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13275/what-exactly-does-generateconditions-do) or [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46453/when-to-use-generateconditions-true).

The gist is that, for multiple integration, automatically checking conditions and issuing provisos for all but the final integration is typically both too costly (in speed) and too likely to create impediments to finishing the integration (due to overly difficult provisos). `Integrate` is reasonably capable of finding path singularities and issuing provisos to avoid them, but working with such provisos in subsequent integrations is not so simple. Also this is touched upon in the article found [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228562940_Symbolic_definite_%28and_indefinite%29_integration_methods_and_open_issues).

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I would only elaborate to say that Mathematica is plainly giving a wrong answer and should be fixed so it gives the right answer (that the integral does not converge). Your “has to do with the default behavior or GenerateConditions” not only clarifies that Mathematica’s answer is wrong, it provides a workaround to assist Mathematica in finding the correct answer. Of course, Wolfram should not have used an invalid solution method by default and left it up to the user to specify an obscure option to get a right answer. This is one of my great frustrations with Mathematica!

Comment: Were  that default behavior in Mathematica to change, many multivariate integrals it currently handles would simply hang.

Comment: I should add that my remarks do not mean I am happy with the present situation regarding multivariate definite integrals. Just that there is no quick resolution in terms of `Integrate` internals.

Answer (score 5):

This s not an answer but an extended comment about results with v10.1

```
$Version
```

> "10.1.0  for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)"

```
Integrate[1/(x y z), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

> 0

```
Integrate[1./(x y z), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

> 0

However,`NIntegrate` gives the a large result in either case with convergence warnings

```
NIntegrate[1/(x y z), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

> 3.884415286001312*^12

```
NIntegrate[1./(x y z), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

> 3.884415286001312*^12

Integrating over a region,

```
rgn = ImplicitRegion[
   0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1,
   {x, y, z}];

Integrate[1/(x y z), Element[{x, y, z}, rgn]]
```

> 0

```
Integrate[1./(x y z), Element[{x, y, z}, rgn]]
```

> 3.884415286001312*^12

This is the same result as with `NIntegrate`; however, without the convergence warning.

Following the advice of @Daniel Lichtblau to use `GenerateConditions->True` gives mixed results

```
Integrate[1/(x y z), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
 GenerateConditions -> True]
```

[image]

> Integrate[1/(x*y*z), {x, 0, 1}, 
>          {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
>          GenerateConditions -> True]

```
Integrate[1./(x y z), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
 GenerateConditions -> True]
```

[image]

> 1.*Integrate[1/(x*y*z), {x, 0, 1}, 
>        {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
>        GenerateConditions -> True]

```
Integrate[1/(x y z), Element[{x, y, z}, rgn], GenerateConditions -> True]
```

> Infinity

```
Integrate[1./(x y z), Element[{x, y, z}, rgn], GenerateConditions -> True]
```

> 3.884415286001312*^12