# Mathematica 11: Mellin transform conditions?

Tags: integral-transforms

Consider the expression

```
fun = 1/(y^2-1)^a;
```

If I do the [Mellin Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform) explicitly, I get a result that involves a few conditions on the parameters `a,s`

```
Integrate[(y)^(s - 1)fun, {y, 0, Infinity}]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[ 1/2 Gamma[ 1 - a] (Gamma[a - s/2]/Gamma[1 - s/2] + ((-1)^-a Gamma[s/2])/ Gamma[1 - a + s/2]) , 2 a > Re[s] && Re[s] > 0 && a < 1]`

However, if I just use the Mellin transform function, no restrictions on the parameters `a,s` appear:

```
MellinTransform[fun, y, s]
```

> `1/2 Gamma[ 1 - a] (Gamma[a - s/2]/Gamma[1 - s/2] + ((-1)^-a Gamma[s/2])/
>    Gamma[1 - a + s/2])`

Which result should I trust? Are the restrictions really necessary, or is there maybe some analytic continuation going on which the `MellinTransform` function knows about while `Integrate` does not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MellinTransform.html):
[image]

Your case:

```
MellinTransform[1/(y^2 - 1)^a, y, s, GenerateConditions -> True]
```

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[
>   1/2 Gamma[1 - a] (Gamma[a - s/2]/Gamma[1 - s/2] + ((-1)^-a Gamma[s/2])/Gamma[1 - a + s/2]), 
>   2 a > Re[s] && Re[s] > 0 && a < 1
> ]
> ```

Comment: Wonder why this option is off by default. If no conditions are given, the result is wrong. There is no instance I can think of, in which not giving the conditions would be useful.

Comment: @Kagaratsch To be honest, I don't know. For computing formal results, it's useful. It's also less verbose. I found this answer though: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46492/4346