# Paths integrals in the complex plane

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I can't find how to calculate path integrals of complex functions in the complex plane.

For example: $$\oint_{\mid z \mid =2}\frac{1-e^z+z}{z^3 (z-1)^2}dz$$

Comment: It'll  be helpful if you provide the Mathematica code you've used

Comment: Parametrize `z = Exp[I*t]` and have `t` vary from 0 to 2*Pi

Comment: Are you sure this question is related to *Mathematica* ?

Comment: Related (possibly duplicate): [Complex line integral](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19715/245) and [Definite Integral over a path](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20300/245)

Answer (score 26):

For this function:

```
f[z_] := (1 - E^z + z)/(z^3 (z - 1)^2)
```

there are no branch cuts in the complex plane therefore we simply use Cauchy integral theorem and the related formula of the complex residue, i.e. we sum up residues of the function $f$ in the circle $\mid z \mid =2$.  Let's denote $$int = \oint_{\mid z \mid =2}\frac{1-e^z+z}{z^3 (z-1)^2}dz$$ 
Now we have:

```
int = 2 Pi I Total[ Residue[f[z], {z, #}] & /@ {0, 1}] // Simplify
```

> ```
>  I (-11 + 4 E) Pi
> ```

Alternatively we can parametrize `z` over the given circle `z -> 2 E^(I t)`:

```
(1 - E^z + z)/(z^3 (z - 1)^2) /. z -> 2 E^(I t)
```

> ```
> (E^(-3 I t) (1 - E^(2 E^(I t)) + 2 E^(I t)))/(8 (-1 + 2 E^(I t))^2)
> ```

and `d z -> 2 I E^(I t) d t`, now we have:

```
Integrate[(E^(-3 I t)(1 - E^(2 E^(I t)) + 2 E^(I t)))/( 8(-1 + 2 E^(I t))^2) 2 I E^(I t), 
          {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

> ```
> I (-11 + 4 E) Pi
> ```

```
% // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 20):

If a numerical answer is good enough you can just enter the path. As @Artes said it doesn't have to be the circle exactly.

```
NIntegrate[f[z], {z, 2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I, -2 + 2 I, -2 - 2 I, 2 - 2 I}]
(* 0. - 0.398582 I *)
```

Check :

```
I (-11 + 4 E) Pi // N
(* 0. - 0.398582 I *)
```

Another suggestion from @Artes (thanks !) : one can use symbolic integration as well and

```
Integrate[f[z], {z, 2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I, -2 + 2 I, -2 - 2 I, 2 - 2 I}] // FullSimplify
```

will reproduce his result.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, I think it shouldn't be deleted since as far as I know this way of computing integrals couldn't be found in documentation.

Comment: @Artes, FYI this usage is the third bullet point under Details and Options for NIntegrate.

Comment: @chuy Thanks, in fact there is it, but what about `Integrate`? Perhaps there is it somewhere, but couldn't find it.