# Complex integrals and residues

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I have a question.
I try to integrate this function:

```
Integrate[Exp[I k z]*Exp[-Sqrt[k^2 - A^2]x]*Exp[-k^2*L^2/4]/Sqrt[k^2 - A^2], 
    {k, -Infinity, -A}]
```

But Mathematica doesn't want to give an answer. It just prints me my integral.

The same story I have when I try to calculate the residue of this function at the infinity point, for example.

What's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the syntax, I think it's because this integration doesn't have a analytic solution (at least _Mathematica_ doesn't know it), consider `NIntegrate` if a numeric solution is enough for you.

Comment: You should first take a look e.g. here; [How to calculate contour integrals with Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34073/how-to-calculate-contour-integrals-with-mathematica/34090#34090), perhaps this can be a simpler help: [Paths integrals in the complex plane](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36961/paths-integrals-in-the-complex-plane/36962#36962).