# Integrate with complex limits

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I am trying to understand how Mathematica handles the Integral with complex limits.

```
NIntegrate[Exp[Sin[y]], {y, I, 2}]
```

How does NIntegrate works for this limits?

Comment: This [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36961/paths-integrals-in-the-complex-plane) is closely related. Read the both answers in case of  any doubts, namely you can choose any compact curve starting from `I` and ending in `2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`EvaluationMonitor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluationMonitor.html) to see what points were sampled:

```
{res,data}=Reap[NIntegrate[Exp[Sin[y]],{y,I,2},EvaluationMonitor:>Sow[y]]];
```

Here is a plot of the data showing that [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html) uses a straight line contour:

[image]

```
Graphics[{PointSize[Large],Red,Point@@ReIm@data},Axes->True,AxesLabel->{Re,Im}]
```

Compare this to choosing a different contour:

```
{res,data}=Reap[NIntegrate[Exp[Sin[y]], {y, I, I+2, 2}, EvaluationMonitor:>Sow[y]]];
Graphics[{PointSize[Large],Red,Point@@ReIm@data},Axes->True,AxesLabel->{Re,Im}]
```

[image]