# Computation of complex integral over circle

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I am beginning Mathematica user. Please show me the syntax on how to compute the following complex integral in Mathematica:

$\int_{|z-2i|=10} \frac{dz}{z(1-e^{-5z})}$

What I really want is a subroutine that takes $f$ - my function and $c$ - my circle and compute the following complex integral. Samples in documentation force me to alter $f$ every time. But calculation insets relies on residues, so I want to have clean syntax.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The documentation here has examples for Integral along a complex line, Along a piecewise linear contour in the complex plane and also Along a circular contour in the complex plane  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the comment. I do not think your reference is practical. Imagine my that analytic express of $f$ has 30 instances of $z$. I do not want to covert every $z$ to parametric form. What I want is to have one unified function for different function $f$ and different contour $c$.

Comment: If you're actually computing residues, why not use `Residue[]`?

Comment: J.M. I already used it, but I wanted to know to compute the integral having $f$ and $c$ with Mathematica in natural and elegant way. With residues one has to know something about what is he doing. I have 2 parameters - cicle and function, how do I symblicaly integrate? Since Mathematica can compute residues, it must be able to handle this task.

Comment: What code have you written for your `f`?

Comment: f[_z] = 1 / (z*(1 - Exp[-5*z]))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paths integrals in the complex plane](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36961/paths-integrals-in-the-complex-plane).  Also this can be instructive [How to calculate contour integrals with Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34073/how-to-calculate-contour-integrals-with-mathematica/34090#34090)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    z = 2*I + 10*E^(I*t);
    NIntegrate[10/(z + (1 - E^(-5*z))), {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]

(*   2.07045 - 0.0177716 I  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I do not need numeric value, I need symbolic one.

Comment: Then try `Integrate` instead, but I doubt that it will work.