# How to calculate this integral symbolically?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How to calculate the following integral *symbolically with Mathematica*:

$$ I = \int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(x^2+a^2)(\ln^2x+\pi^2)} $$

where $a>0$ is a real number.

PS: from complex analysis, we can determine it:

$$ I = \frac{2\pi}{(4\ln^2a+\pi^2) \, a} - \frac{1}{a^2+1} $$

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of e.g. [How to calculate contour integrals with Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34073/how-to-calculate-contour-integrals-with-mathematica/34090#34090) or [Paths integrals in the complex plane](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36961/paths-integrals-in-the-complex-plane),  unless you show what you have tried. Perhaps there are exact duplicates somewhere on MSE.

Comment: The special case $a=1$ cannot be done by `Integrate` (*Mathematica* v11.1).  So, without providing significant help, it is unlikely it would be able to do it for more general $a$.