# How to get the integral sign for a path?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Here a example of the integral sign :  $\int _C$

How to get this notion in MMA ?

I tried this input, but it was not possible.

**EDIT**

Looking at the CountourIntegral command and the variation of it.
*Esc cint Esc*, gives the countour integral symbol

Comment: Make "Esc+intt+Esc". Does it help?

Comment: Thanks, this is not working :  "Esc+intt+Esc" , nothing happens in the notebook ?
Working is  "Esc+int+Esc", 
I think that the notation is possible as it seems , but the actual calculated integral is without the C notATION in MMA.

Comment: Do you just need the notation or do you want to calculate the integral over a contour C? For the notation alone, I'm pretty sure "Esc+intt+Esc" should work, and if it's not working then open Palletes -> Writing Assistant, and in the "Typesetting" section there are integrals with limits. In the upper limit, highlight it and press Backspace - this will remove it. In the lower limit you can place "C".

Comment: See https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TwoDimensionalExpressionInput.html#453224886  or use the inline TeX input.

Comment: @mszynisz , thanks , i must look further into this. Notation and for calculation.

Comment: @Michael E2, thanks , must figure out this further.

Comment: @janhardo Perhaps related is this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36961/paths-integrals-in-the-complex-plane In here they show how to integrate over a polygonal path in the complex plane: `Integrate[(1 - E^z + z)/(z^3 (z - 1)^2), {z, 2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I, -2 + 2 I, -2 - 2 I, 2 - 2 I}] // FullSimplify`.

Comment: @ mszynisz, it shows that the Integrate symbol has ( the S ) has no attached sign C (contour)  to it.

Comment: Esc cint Esc....  gives the countour integral