# How to Integrate trivial products of DiracDelta

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

A long while ago I was able to integrate with *Mathematica*:
$$\int_0^1 \delta(1-x)\delta(x) f(x) \,dx = 0$$
using `Integrate[DiracDelta[1-x] DiracDelta[x] f[x], {x, 0, 1}]`.  Now, it just returns unevaluated.  What can I do to make it integrate it?

Comment: don't we need to make some assumption on `f` to eval this?  Suppose `f[x]=1/(DiracDelta[1 - x] DiracDelta[x])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split up the interval of integration:

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[1 - x] DiracDelta[x] f[x], {x, 0, 1/2, 1}]
(*  0  *)
```

Still, it seems a bit inconvenient.

Comment: I cannot locate any documentation on splitting up the interval of integration. Can you please provide a reference/link to this feature. Thanks.

Comment: @BobHanlon I can't remember how I knew this.  You can find an example in the docs for `Integrate` (search for "contour").  See also http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20300.

Answer (score 1):

With v10.0.2 it appears to work only for infinite bounds or using `NIntegrate`

```
$Version
```

> "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)"

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[1 - x] DiracDelta[x] f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> 0

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[x, 1 - x]  f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> 0

```
NIntegrate[DiracDelta[1 - x] DiracDelta[x] f[x], {x, 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 5]
```

> 0.

```
NIntegrate[DiracDelta[x, 1 - x]  f[x], {x, 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 5]
```

> 0.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the integral should give zero even with finite bounds. This workaround seems to give the desired result:

```
Limit[
 Integrate[
  DiracDelta[1 - x] DiracDelta[x] f[x], {x, ϵ, 1}], ϵ -> 0]

(* ==> 0 *)
```

But it works only because it effectively cuts off the lower bound and thus the lower delta function.