# Numerical integration over a circle contour

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to numerically integrate the following function

$$f(p) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}\frac{1}{p}\exp\left(\frac{a^{2}}{2}\frac{1}{p}+\frac{b^{2}}{2}p\right)dp$$

where the contour $\Gamma$ is a circle with radius $r$ less than unity and let a and b to be unity

I wrote it like this on Mathematica, but I don't know a possible way to write the integral limits

```
NIntegrate[1/(2*Pi*I*p)*Exp[1/(2*p) + 1/2*p], {p, ,]
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This link may be helpful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34090/1997

Comment: Okay, try making the substitution $p=r\exp(i t)$, and take the limits from $0$ to $2\pi$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working, please add it as an answer

Comment: The sub-section "Applications" of the section "Examples" in [NIntegrate's function page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html) has examples on doing integrals over lines, surfaces, volumes, and regions.

Comment: Although this is about numerical integration, the maths is exactly the same as in [Complex line integral](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19715/complex-line-integral). In particular, you can use my answer there to do the integral simply in the form `f[p_]:=1/p Exp[1/(2 p)+1/2 p]; (1/(2 Pi I)) contourIntegrate[ Cos[t]+I Sin[t], f,{t,0,2 Pi}]`. The answer is `BesselI[0,1]`.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Posted for review.. I'm not sure if this is correct.

making the substitution per comments, `p=r Exp[I t]` so that 
`dp == r I Exp[I t] dt == I p dt` :

```
With[{r = 2, a = 1, b = 1}, (1/ (2 Pi I)) NIntegrate[
   I Exp[a^2/(2 (r Exp[I t])) + b^2/2 (r Exp[I t])],
   {t, 0 , 2 Pi}]]
```

> 1.26607 + 4.24074*10^-15 I

(Note this agrees with the `BesselI[0, 1]` result per comments)

for the record I first though we could use the *region* integrate capability:

```
With[{r = 2, a = 1, b = 1}, 
    (1/ (2 Pi I)) NIntegrate[
       1/((x + I y))*Exp[a^2/(2*(x + I y)) + b^2/2*(x + I y)],
       Element[{x, y}, Circle[{0, 0}, r]]]]
```

> 2.82716*10^-16 - 1.13032 I

which is the same result as we get with the first sub but with dp/dt = r:

```
With[{r = 2, a = 1,  b = 1},
   (1/ (2 Pi I)) NIntegrate[
   1/(Exp[I t])*Exp[a^2/(2*(r Exp[I t])) + b^2/2*(r Exp[I t])],
   {t, 0 , 2 Pi}]]
```

> 7.0679*10^-17 - 1.13032 I

Comment: Note that `BesselI[1,1]` is approximately $0.565159 \approx \frac{1}{2}( 1.13032)$.  So your second and third expressions are not giving the same result, probably because the two integrals aren't over the same circle ($r = 2$ for the second, $r = 1$ for the third.)

Comment: right, the first two run with `r=1` agree with the `BesselI` result for `r=1` ( That is they are all 3 right or all three wrong ! )

Comment: See [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) for what looks to be the exact integral in question (with $a = b = 1$ in our integral and $z = 1, n = 0$ in that expression.)  Note that this implies that the correct answer should be $I_0(1) \approx 1.26607$, which suggests to me that the last answer is the correct one and the first three are wrong.  (Not sure why, though.)

Comment: On further reflection, I suspect that's what's happening here is that the integration over regions implicitly assumes a line element of the form $dl = \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2}$ (or $dl = \sqrt{dr^2 + r^2 \, d\theta^2}$) as we integrate around the curve.  But for a complex integral in the complex plane, we should be using $dl = dx + i dy$ instead (or $dl = e^{i\theta} dr + i r e^{i\theta} \, d\theta$.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert i think that's right, reordered the results in the answer.