Contour integral with radius infinite
How can I get compute a contour integral of the function $f(z)=\exp(i z)/z$ in the upper circle with center in $(0,0)$ and radius $R$? I want verify that $\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_C f(x)=0$ in mathematica. I try with  ContourIntegrate.

"I try with ContourIntegrate", yeah it's the right tool, how did you try? Please show us your code.

I am find a command as CountourIntegrate[[Exp[I z]/z, z /[Element] Circle[{0,0},R]] but only with the upper circle

If you need upper circle, then you need to define the upper circle: ContourIntegrate[Exp[I  z]/z, z \[Element] Circle[{0, 0}, R, {0, Pi}],   Assumptions -> R > 0] Please read the document of CountourIntegrate and Circle more carefully: https://i.sstatic.net/6i8mrbBM.png

Why do people want to close this question?  While the answer is somewhere in the documentation I for one did not know that Circle took a 3rd argument so it is usefull to have it here?

@chris Well I'd say deciding if an answer "is easily found in the documentation" is somewhat subjective. Consider vote to reopen? I myself won't be against the decision if the community decides to reopen it.

The following does the job.
ContourIntegrate[Exp[I  z]/z, z \[Element] Circle[{0, 0}, R, {0, Pi}],  Assumptions -> R > 0]


I (\[Pi] - 2 SinIntegral[R])

Limit[%,R->Infinity]


0


I am not sure this is what you want and I am not sure the result is correct but...
Let's define the contour
 z = R  Exp[ I  t];

Check it:
ParametricPlot[ReIm[R  Exp[ I  t] /. R -> 1] // Evaluate, {t, 0, Pi}]


Define the function to integrate
f[z_] = Exp[I  z]/z;

Carry out the integration
tt = Integrate[f[z]  D[z, t], {t, 0, Pi}, Assumptions -> R > 0]

Take the limit
Limit[tt, R -> Infinity]

(* 0 *)

It should be D[z,t] instead of Abs[D[z, t]] in the above (see, for example, Wiki for info).

@user64494 I should I have known since I wrote the original post which lead to ContourIntegrate :-)  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13734/1089
