# How to do this complex integration on the real line?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, symbolic, complex

$m, r$ are parameters in the following integral:

```
Integrate[z Exp[I z r]/Sqrt[z^2 + m^2], {z, -∞, ∞}]
```

How to do this integration directly? The result should be `2 I m BesselK[1, mr]`. [This post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13721/finding-residues-of-multi-dimensional-complex-functions/13728#13728) may be helpful, but I haven't found anything to solve this question.

As suggested by b.gatessucks, this integration can be converted to the following one which can be computed by Mathematica:

```
Integrate[Exp[I z r]/Sqrt[z^2 + m^2], {z, -∞, ∞}]
```

and its result is `2 BesselK[0, m r]`. But this method may be not general, because we do not know which form can be recognized by Mathematica for other similar problems.

Comment: You can omit the `z` in the numerator, integrate and then differentiate with respect to `r`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Yeap! Thanks! But how to do the new integration?

Comment: Use `Assumptions -> r > 0 && m > 0` which will assume that `m` and `r` are positive and real numbers. For a detailed discussion of contour integration I recommend e.g. this post [How to calculate contour integrals with Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34073/how-to-calculate-contour-integrals-with-mathematica/34090#34090).

Comment: It diverges. What result were you expecting to obtain?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks! I update the question.

Comment: @Artes Thanks! But I do not think that post helpful, because the result here is a Bessel function and the integration is already on the real line.

Comment: @EdenHarder Contour integration is applied also for purely real integrals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you want the principal value, since the integral is divergent.

```
Integrate[
 z Exp[I z r]/Sqrt[z^2 + m^2], {z, -∞, ∞}, 
 PrincipalValue -> True, Assumptions -> m > 0 && r ∈ Reals]
(*
  2 I m BesselK[1, m Abs[r]] Sign[r]
*)
```

If `r > 0`, then it agrees with your expected answer.

---

Another derivation, although it seems more difficult to justify (multiply by `Exp[-Abs[a] z]` and take the limit as `a -> 0`):

```
intplus  = Integrate[(E^(-a z) z Exp[I z r]) / Sqrt[m^2 + z^2], {z, 0, ∞}, 
   Assumptions -> m > 0 && a > 0 && r ∈ Reals];
intminus = Integrate[(E^(a z)  z Exp[I z r]) / Sqrt[m^2 + z^2], {z, -∞, 0}, 
   Assumptions -> m > 0 && a > 0 && r ∈ Reals];
FullSimplify[intminus + intplus /. a -> 0, m > 0 && r > 0]
(*
   2 I m BesselK[1, m r]
*)
```

where the parts are

```
{intminus, intplus}
(*
   {  1/2  m π (BesselY[1, m (a + I r)] + StruveH[-1, m (a + I r)]),
    -(1/2) m π (BesselY[1, m (a - I r)] + StruveH[-1, m (a - I r)])}
*)
```